# C# - SMTP Gmail hangs on send. Worked the first time

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail, port

I'm currently developing an application where a file is downloaded from a server, attaches it to an email and sends it to the entered gmail-address. The first time I tried it, it worked fine. When I tried it the second time, the hanging begun, and it hasn't worked since.

Here is my code:

```
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    mail.From = new MailAddress(fran);
                    mail.To.Add(till);
                    mail.Subject = amne;
                    mail.Body = text;

                    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
                    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("file.txt");
                    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

                    SmtpServer.Port = 465;
                    SmtpServer.Timeout = 30000;
                    SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, pw);
                    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

                    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                    SmtpServer.Dispose();
                    mail.Dispose();
```

I've tried ports 587, 465 and 25 aswell as opening them in the Windows Firewall. I've tried disabling Avast! AntiVirus, running as administrator and restarting my computer. Running once and only once makes me think its some kind of caching issue, but what?

I appreciate all tips and suggestions, fire away!

Thanks in advance,
Fredrik

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, the problem is you are using the wrong port. You must use port 587

Comment: All ports have been tried. Besides, I thought port 587 was TLS and not SSL?

Comment: I've tested your code in my laptop and it works with port 587, with SSL enabled. Your problem is not in your app. I'm at home in a LAN with NAT, my Windows 8 firewall is on and didn't enabled on purpose any port. Try configuring your gmail account in any windows mail client and check if it works, I bet it won't work because of the same reason your code does not.

Comment: Outlook works fine, which is odd indeed... And as I said it worked the first time, what causes it not to work now?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying sending smtp mail with Powerbuilder and came across the same hanging situation. Not sure if it helps on the C++ platform but what I did to resolve the issue was to put a newer version of cl32.dll (of course, talking about Windows).